# Android How do I order an array based on integers from another array

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I have two arrays each filled with the same number of values (although the number of values in each array will stay the same, the number of these values can increase or decrease etc.)

The first array list has a list of names e.g.

- Sam
- Dean
- Alice
- Jane
- Steve

The second array list has a list of index locations which I would like the above items to be stored at with a 3rd list-array e.g.

2nd array index locations.

- 3
- 2
- 5
- 1
- 4

I have used arraylists as below:
ArrayList namelist = new ArrayList();

Comment: Is this task from an assignment or homework? ;)

Comment: Neither, part of a program I'm wrighting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply sort the list with names. You can use `Collections.sort()` because the strings are compareable. Then create the new list an add the string in the order of the indices.

```
List<String> newList = new ArrayList<>(); // or new ArrayList<String>(); for source level below 1.7
Collections.sort(nameslist);

for(Integer idx : indexList)
{
    newList.add(nameslist.get(idx - 1));
}
```

Comment: Then you have to provide your code, otherwise i cannot help.

Comment: I get the error: '<>' operator is not allowed for source level below 1.7. What fix would you suggest other than changing source level

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a third array with the same size as the other two. Then you have to use the values of intArray as indices for the sortedStrArray like so:

```
public class JavaApplication
{
    // Utilisation
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // The arrays are just here to make the initialization shorter. 
        // You can initialize strArrayList and
        // intArrayList from the beginning with the add method if you want.
        String strArray[] = new String[] { "Sam", "Dean", "Alice", "Jane", "Steve" };
        Integer intArray[] = new Integer[] { 3, 2, 5, 1, 4 };

        // Put array data in ArrayLists
        List<String> strArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strArray));
        List<Integer> intArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(intArray));

        List<String> sortedList = sortArrayListByIndices(strArrayList, intArrayList);

        // Output order should be: Jane, Dean, Sam, Steve, Alice
        for(String str : sortedList)
        {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    // Implementation
    public static List<String> sortArrayListByIndices(List<String> strArrayList, 
                                                      List<Integer> intArrayList)
    {
        String sortedStrArray[] = new String[strArrayList.size()];

        int i = 0;
        for(String str : strArrayList) // Iterator is better style
        {
            // indices start with 1, array starts with 0
            final int index = intArrayList.get(i) - 1; 

            sortedStrArray[index] = str;
            i++;
        }

        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sortedStrArray));
    }
}
```

The desired algorithm has its own method now and I wrote a little program that utilizes/tests it.